# Why is the parameter type of the bcadd method in PHP a string?

Tags: php, floating-point

When I look at the description of [floating point numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float) in the php documentation.
I get a warning like this:
[image: pic-1]

I clicked on the link about [arbitrary precision math functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) because I need higher precision, then I got bcadd methoad.

```php
echo floor((0.1+0.7)*10);
//result : 7

echo floor(bcadd(0.1+0.7)*10);
//result : 8
```

It works, but I noticed that the parameter type of the bcadd method is a string.

[image: pic-2]

I just don't understand why a parameter type is a string as a math function.
Any opinion would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: You can also see that it returns a string.

Comment: If it was an integer, then what would be a point of that function? If it was a float then your maths would be wrong. Only strings can ensure high precision and large numbers in PHP.

Comment: Essentially all common representations of general numbers (that is, numbers like 34, 7.13•10^5, not special or named/described numbers, like π or the square root of two) are strings in part or full as computer scientists define them: a string is any finite sequence of symbols chosen from an alphabet. For integers, we commonly use a finite sequence of symbols 0-9, with an optional - in front. For floating-point numbers, the significand (fraction portion) is commonly a finite sequence of symbols 0-9 with an optional . and possibly also a - and an exponent designation.

Comment: So any arbitrary precision calculator is going to use some form of string. The question is which form. Since the BCMath functions support arbitrary precision, they let you pass an arbitrary number of digits. The way they choose to do this is by letting you pass a character string. There are other ways of passing an arbitrary number of digits—it could be an array of other integers of one sort or another, with the end designated by some sentinel or separately passed length (although a finite representation for the length imposes a limit on the length, so then the length is not truly arbitrary).

Comment: Additionally, I suspect the PHP BCMath functions are based on the same underlying software as the Unix `bc` command, which is designed for human use through the command line and hence takes inputs in the form of numbers typed by a human.